# C++/CLI Including Native Functions with parameters defaulted to NULL

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I hope this isn't a dupe; I fear I don't know right thing to search so I'll just explain my problem.

I'm wrapping a large 3rd Party C/C++ API with C++/CLI so I can then use those final assemblies in a .Net C# plugin framework for a larger application.
The API does come with some documentation, headers, dll, and lib files so the first setup was easy: in Visual Studio 2013 I started a CLR/Class Library project add the files to the folder, add include directories/dependencies/using directories to the configuration sheets.
However, trying to use the exported global functions of the API throw a list of errors because the parameters are defaulted to NULL

```
 APPIMPEXP void GetPartner(TCHAR* pHst = NULL)
```

Fails because(C2065) 'NULL' : undeclared identifier

So prior to included I tried one ugly hack after another

```
#define NULL nullptr;
```

Same line now has the error(C2143) syntax error:missing ')' before ;

```
#define NULL 0
```

Same error.

```
extern "C"
{
  #include "apidll.h"
}
```

Same error

I've done very little with CLI before this, but I'm surprised I'm stumped so early.  Is my only option PInvoke?  I had initially tried to avoid that way because the API is heavily dependent on callbacks and I had finally determined a way to marshal delegates to callbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#define NULL nullptr;
```

This one strikes me as the most correct of the things you tried to do (although someone more versed in C++ may have a different opinion). However, there's an error there: Remove the semicolon. Remember that #defines are simple text substitution, so that method becomes `GetPartner(TCHAR* pHst = nullptr;)`, which is not correct.

Comment: oh my.. that's embarrassing..Thanks